# Registration form is not registering users

Tags: php, forms, validation

I want to validate a registration form and send an email to the client once registration is successful. My form is being validated but once I click the register button, literally nothing happens, I don't get an error message, or redirection to the login page and neither is the user created.

```php
<?php 

    include_once(session_start());

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'] ;


    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // redirect back and display error

        if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $session_error= 'Please enter your email';
        } elseif ($_POST['email']){

            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $session_error= 'Invalid Email Format';
            }
        }else{
            $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
            $session_error = 'Last Name should be filled';
        } elseif ($_POST['last_name']) {
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $last_name)) {
                $session_error = 'last Name can only contain letters and white spaces';
            }
        } else {
            $last_name = test_input($_POST['last_name']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
            $session_error = 'First Name should be filled';
        } elseif ($_POST['first_name']) {
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $first_name)) {
                $session_error = 'First Name can only contain letters and white spaces';
            }
        } else {
            $first_name = test_input($_POST['first_name']);
        }

        $_SESSION["error"] = $session_error;

        header("Location: register.php ");
    }else{
        // count all users
        $allUsers = scandir("db/users/");
        $countAllUsers = count($allUsers);
        $newUserId = ($countAllUsers -2) +1;


    // assign ID to the new user
     $userObject =[
    'id' => $newUserId,
    'first_name' => $first_name, 
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT ),  // password hashing

        ];
        // check if user already exists

        // assign the next ID to the new user
        // count($users =>2, next should then be ID 3


        for($counter = 0; $counter < $countAllUsers; $counter++) {
            $currentUser = $allUsers[$counter];

            if($currentUser == $email . ".json"){
                $_SESSION["error"] = "User already exists " . $first_name;
                header("Location: register.php");
                die();
            }

        }

        header("Location: login.php");
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }
```

My register.php:

```php
<body>

    <?php include_once('lib/header.php'); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && !empty ($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
      // redirect to dashboard
      header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }


    ?>
    <h3><strong>Register</strong></h3>

    <form method="POST" action="processRegister.php">
      <p>
      <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && !empty($_SESSION['error'])){
     echo "<span style='color:red'> " . $_SESSION['error'] . "</span>";

     session_destroy();
    }
    ?>
      </p>
    <p>
    <label>First Name</label><br/>
    <input 
    <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
    echo "value=" . $_SESSION['first_name'];
        }
    ?>
    type="text"name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"  /></p>
    <p> <label>Last Name</label><br/>
    <input
    <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['last_name'])) {
    echo "value=" . $_SESSION['last_name'];
        }
    ?>
    type="text"name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"  /></p>
    <p> <label>Email</label><br/>
    <input  <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo "value=" . $_SESSION['email'];
        }
    ?> type="text"name="email" placeholder="Email"  /> </p>
    <p> <label>Password</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  /> </p>

    <p> <button type="submit">Register</button>  </p>

    </form>

    <?php  include('lib/footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code uses form variables before you've checked the request-method - that should be done inside that `if`. But, when it's validated inside the `if`, it does a header redirect back to `register.php` regardless of whether you found any errors. And why do you use that method to assign a new user ID? Wouldn't it be better to have an auto-increment column in the database table and use that?

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: You've got quite a lot of code there, could you not reduce it to a [mcve]? And "nothing happens" isn't a great problem statement: What exactly do you expect to happen, how are you determining it isn't, and what debugging have you done to determine where it stops working?

Comment: sorry for the huge amount of code, it's my first time on stack. what I meant by nothing happens is that after the form has been filled, and the register button is clicked, nothing changes, I don't get a an error message neither is the user created.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a name attribut value to your submit input element.
For example:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-register" value="Register">
```

And to verif in your PHP script if submit has been clicked:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-register'])) {
    // Do you stuff here
}
```

Comment: That's one approach to determining if the form has been submitted, but `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` is probably fine.